# Howto define TAB and S-TAB in keymap of custom mode

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode, keymap

I'm trying to bind the TAB and shift TAB keys to a custom readonly buffer mode. The skeleton of the mode looks like this:

```
;; 8< --- exmode.el -------

(defun exmode-i ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Pressed i"))

(defun exmode-tab ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Pressed tab"))

(defun exmode-s-tab ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Pressed shift-tab"))

(defvar ex-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-keymap))) ;;
    (suppress-keymap map t)
    (define-key map  "i"       'exmode-i)
    (define-key map  [tab]     'exmode-tab)
    (define-key map  [S-tab]   'exmode-s-tab)
    map)
  "keymap `ex-mode'.")

(define-derived-mode ex-mode special-mode "ex-mode"
  "Example mode"
  :group 'ex-mode
  (buffer-disable-undo)
  (setq truncate-lines t)
  (setq buffer-read-only t)
  )

(defun setup-exmode-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((buffer (generate-new-buffer "*exmode*")))
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (funcall 'ex-mode)
      (display-buffer buffer))
    ))

(provide 'exmode)
;; 8< --- exmode.el -------
```

When I `(require 'exmode)` and `M-x setup-exmode-buffer` I get a buffer where the `i` is correcly bound, however the `tab` and `s-tab` bindings are strange:

Doing a `C-h k` + key shows:

When running in term mode (`-nw`) running under KDE `Konsole` terminal emulator:

- press `tab` : bound to `<tab>`, runs `(indent-for-tab-command &optional ARG)`
- press `s-tab` : bound to `<backtab>`, `<backtab> not defined`.

When running in GUI mode :

- press `tab` : bound to `<tab>`, runs `'exmode-tab`, which is the behaviour I want
- press `s-tab` : bound to `<backtab>`,   `<backtab> not defined`.

How can I make `exmode-tab` and `exmode-s-tab` to be called when pressing `tab` and `s-tab` in both term and GUI mode?
I'm running Emacs 27.0.50.

Comment: By looking at what C-h k returns, and trial and error, I found `(kbd "TAB")` and `(kbd "<backtab>")` as the key designation seem to work.  I'll be happy to see someone explaining how this should be handled...

Comment: Use `(kbd "TAB")` (or use `(kbd "<tab>")`, if you want to distinguish `C-i` from the `<tab>` key) and `(kbd "<backtab>")`, in place of `[tab]` and `[S-tab]`.

Comment: I peeked into Magit's code an there `(kbd "C-i")` (for tab) and `[backtab]` (for s-tab) is used. I wonder what the difference and mechanisms behind  `[tab]` `(kbd "TAB")` `(kbd "<tab>)` `(kbd "C-i")` are? And s-tab:  `[s-tab]` `(kbd "<backtab>")` `[backtab]`.

Comment: @Drew @JeanPierre: There combinations work: `(kbd "<tab>")` and `(kbd "<backtab>")` as well as `(kbd "C-i")` and `[backtab]` . Thanks.

Comment: `s-` is the Super modifier, not the Shift modifier (that's `S-`, not `s-`). You will never go wrong if you use `kbd`.